# KNN Classifier using cross validation

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, knn, cross-validation

I am trying to implement KNN classifier using the cross validation approach where I have different images of a certain character for training(e.g 5 images) and another two for testing. Now I get the idea of the cross validation by simply choosing the K with the least error value when training & then using it with the test data to find how accurate my results are.

My question is how do I train images in matlab to get my K value? Do I compare them and try to find mismatch or what?!

Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of you need to define your task precisely. F.ex Given an image I in R^(MxN) we wish to classify I as an image containing faces or an image without faces.

I often work with pixel classifiers, where the task is something like: For an image I decide if each pixel is a face pixel or a non-face pixel.

An important part of defining the task is to make a hypotheses that can be used as basis for training a classifier. F.ex We believe that the distribution of pixel intensities can be used to discriminate images of faces from images not containing faces.

Then you need to select some features that define your image. This can be done in many ways and you should search for what other people do when they analyse the same type of images you are working with.

One widely used method in pixel classification is to use pixel intensity values and do a multi-scale analysis of the image. The idea in multi-scale analysis is that different structures are most evident at different level of blurring called scales. As an illustration consider an image of a tree. Without blurring we notice the fine structure, such as small branches and leafs. When we blur the image we notice the trunk and major branches. This is often used as part of segmentation methods.

When you know your task and the features, you can train a classifier. If you use kNN and cross-validation to find the best k, you should split you dataset in train/testing and then split the training set in train/validate sets. You then train using the reduced training set and use the validation set to decide which k is the best. In the case of binary classification e.g face vs non-face the error rate is often used as a measure of performance.

Finally you use the parameters to train the classifier on the full dataset and estimate its performance on the test set.

**A classification example: With or without milk?**

As a full example, consider images of a cup of coffee taken from above so it shows the rim of the cup surrounding a brownly colored disk. Further assume that all images are scaled and cropped so the diameter of the disk is the same and dimensions of the image are the same. To simplify the task, we convert the color image to grayscale and scale the pixel intensities to the range [0,1].

We want to train a classifier so it can distinguish coffee with milk from coffee without milk. From inspection of histograms of some of the coffee images, we see that each image has two "bumps" in the histogram that are clearly separated. We believe that these bumps correspond to foreground (coffee) and background. Now we make the hypothesis that the average intensity of the foreground can be used to distinguish between coffee+milk/coffee.

To find the foreground pixels we observe that because the foreground/background ratio is the same (by design) we can just find the intensity value that gives us that ratio for each image. Then we calculate the average intensity of the foreground pixels and use this value as a feature for each image.

If we have N images that we have manually labeled, we split this into training and test set. We then calculate the average foreground intensity for each image in the training set, giving us a set of (average foreground intensity, label) values. We want to use kNN where an image is assigned the same class as the majority class of the k closest images. We measure the distance as the absolute value of the difference in average foreground pixel intensity.

We search for the optimal k with cross validation. We use 2-fold cross validation (aka holdout) to find the best k. We test k = {1,3,5} and select the k that gives the least prediction error on the validation set.

Comment: @Silas...Yes I already have train and test data.As I understand from you that I need to define something when training that will be looked for when testing.
For example, if the image contains certain number/color of pixels then it will be matched. The question is, does it need to match completely or at least most of it is present.
Example: First 3 rows of pixels should represent object pixels
Test: First 3 are object pixles but some of the pixels are background pixels...Should this be matched or not?!
Correct me if i am wrong please.

Comment: @omarsafwany I have added an example of the approach. One thing to note is that the difficulty of classification is related to how general the task is. So object recognition/classification in Google streetview is way more difficult than the coffee example.